# Javascript KeyboardEvent in IE 8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, keyboard-events

I got 2 problems with my function, because it displays "Missing part 'Keyboard Event'". I'm working in IE 8 and have no idea, what to change here. Second thing is i would like to change key: 'n' to spacebar, so i would appreciate help for that too. I've tried using keyCode, but maybe i'm doing it wrong.

```
function myFunction () {
  var event = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {
    key: 'n',
    altKey: true
  });
  document.dispatchEvent(event);
}

document.attachEvent('keydown', function (e) {
  if (e.altKey && e.key == "n") {
    // alt or ctrl is pressed
    document.getElementById("blok").innerHTML = "OOHHHH!";
  }
});
```

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Why on earth would anybody still use a discontinued browser from 2009?

Comment: IE8 doesn't support event constructors. When working on a deprecated browser, you've to use deprecated methods too, like [`createEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createEvent).

Comment: @str i can't answer you that question, asked for an update, but looks like they don't even listen to me. :/

Comment: @Teemu, Is there any possibility to create that? I have no idea, how to write it correctly.

Comment: There's a good example at the linked MDN page. Btw. The event name in `attachEvent` arguments must include "on", i.e. `.attachEvent('onkeydown', ...);`.